# Pulseaudion: stream to DLNA player

Tags: pulseaudio, dlna

I wish to stream computer's sound to DLNA-capable player.

Therefore I have install `pulseaudio-dlna`, and all of its components, dependencies, etc.

Sound is getting through the network, however it has a massive 1.5s latency which makes impossible to watch a movie.

```
pacmd list-sinks
* index: 18
    name: <cocktailaudion25mediarenderer_dlna>
    driver: <module-null-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: IDLE
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 1000
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 20.32 ms
    max request: 6 KiB
    max rewind: 6 KiB
    monitor source: 18
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 3
    configured latency: 40.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    module: 46
    properties:
        device.description = "cocktailAudio-N25 MediaRenderer (DLNA)"
        device.class = "abstract"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
```

Especially interested in this line:

```
configured latency: 40.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
```

How can I change it?

Tried so far:

Set fragments in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`:

```
default-fragments = 2
default-fragment-size-msec = 5
```

Didn't help.

Can I kill the latency with pulseaudio somehow? Or it needs to be handled differently by the player?